# Retrieving values from a JSON column in a MariaDB table having certain properties

Tags: json, mariadb

I would appreciate any idea on that.

I've a table named Tests like that:

```
Id|JObject                                                                          |
--+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 2|{"Values":[{"Key":"firstname","Value":"Max"},{"Key":"city","Value":"Berlin"}]} |
 3|{"Values":[{"Key":"firstname","Value":"Erika"},{"Key":"city","Value":"Hamburg"}]}|
```

The DDL for that table looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `Tests` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `JObject` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`JObject`)),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

I was not able to successfully use any of the JSON methods MariaDB is providing (like JSON_VALUE, JSON_SEARCH), to do the following:
Retrieve every dataset from that table having a Key = 'firstname' with a value like '%ax%' and having a key = 'city' with a value like '%burg%'.

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

My query should return the first dataset from that table.
I tried using JSON_VALUE and JSON_SEARCH in the WHERE of the query but I always get NULL as result.

The Maria DB version is 10.11.2-MariaDB-1:10.11.2+maria~ubu2204.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really should be a simpler way to do this, but this at least works:

```
select Id
from Tests
join json_table(JObject, '$.Values[*]' columns(jsonkey text path '$.Key', jsonvalue text path '$.Value')) as jobject
group by Id
having
    sum(jsonkey='firstname' && jsonvalue like '%ax%') and
    sum(jsonkey='city' && jsonvalue like '%burg%');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/il35pzx-)